# Xamarin Studio Android Face Detection

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing mobile app on Xamarin for android I try to use Camera2 class. Everything looks fine but this line occurs problem on convert type. It says (Java.Lang.Object -> Android.Hardware.Camera2.Params.Face[]) This line works on Android Studio but not in C#.

That's code I use on Xamarin. Other than face recognition, all builded requests works fine.
https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/Camera2Basic

```
Face[] faces  = result.Get(CaptureResult.StatisticsFaces);



public class CameraCaptureListener : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback
{
    public FaceTrainActivityFragment Owner { get; set; }
    public File File { get; set; }
    public override void OnCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result)
    {
        Process(result);
    }

    public override void OnCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, CaptureResult partialResult)
    {
        Process(partialResult);
    }

    private void Process(CaptureResult result)
    {
        switch (Owner.mState)
        {

            case FaceTrainActivityFragment.STATE_PREVIEW:
                {
                    if (result.Get(CaptureResult.StatisticsFaces) != null) {
                        //Face[] faces  = result.Get(CaptureResult.StatisticsFaces);
                        //Face[] faces  = (Face[])result.Get(CaptureResult.StatisticsFaces);
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }

    }
}
```

it does not allowed me to compile even if I compile with using hard casting to (Face[]), it gives me same Java.Lang.Object error.

```
    public void CreateCameraPreviewSession()
    {
        try
        {
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.SurfaceTexture;
            if (texture == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("texture is null");
            }

            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }



            // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
            texture.SetDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.Width, mPreviewSize.Height);

            // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
            mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.CreateCaptureRequest(CameraTemplate.Preview);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.AddTarget(surface);

            // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
            List<Surface> surfaces = new List<Surface>();
            surfaces.Add(surface);
            //surfaces.Add(mImageReader.Surface);
            setFaceDetect(mPreviewRequestBuilder, mFaceDetectMode);
            mCameraDevice.CreateCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSessionCallback(this), null);

        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
```

and I am callling CreateCameraPreviewSession inside of Camera State Listener like that

```
public class CameraStateListener : CameraDevice.StateCallback
{
    public FaceTrainActivityFragment owner;
    public override void OnOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice)
    {
        // This method is called when the camera is opened.  We start camera preview here.
        owner.mCameraOpenCloseLock.Release();
        owner.mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        owner.CreateCameraPreviewSession();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> It says (Java.Lang.Object -> Android.Hardware.Camera.Params.Face[]) This line works on Android Studio but not in C#.

From the error you are getting, you are probably using the wrong namespace for `Face`. Instead of `Android.Hardware.Camera.Params.Face`, please use `Android.Hardware.Camera2.Params.Face`.

Comment: Thanks Elvis but it is not the solution I am using Android.Hardware.Camera2.Params library my typing mistake on question.

Comment: Could you post more detailed codes and detailed error log please?

Comment: Hi Elvis, I try to put more information and codes, I hope it helps to you to understand . Thanks very much.

Comment: OK, I reproduced the problem, but unfortunately I didn't find a solution to this. You can post this question on [Xamarin.Android Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/categories/android) for a better help.